# no return value of call procedure mysql

Tags: mysql, null, return-value, procedure

I have a procedure in mysql and it has 4 parameters as Input and 3 parameters of OUTPUT and one param of OUTPUT doesn't return nothing (null).

```
DELIMITER $$
drop procedure if exists `cierreMes`$$
create procedure cierreMes (in tarjeta varchar(100),in bancoBus varchar(100),in mes int,in anyo int, out total int, out nulas int, out erroneas int)
begin
    declare stockActual int default 0;
    declare cantidad int;
    /*declare xcantidad,xnulas,xerroneas int;*/
    declare entrada, salida int default 0;
    declare total int default 0;


    select stock
        into stockActual
    from almacen
    where idProducto = 
        (select idProducto from productos where productos.banco = bancoBus and productos.plastico = tarjeta);

    call entradasSalidas(tarjeta,bancoBus,mes,anyo,@ent,@sal);
    set entrada = @ent;
    set salida = @sal;

    call obtenerMovimientosMes(tarjeta,bancoBus,mes,anyo,@cant,@nul,@err);
    set cantidad = @cant;
    set nulas = @nul;
    set erroneas = @err;    

    set total =(stockActual + entrada) - (salida + cantidad);

    select total; 

end$$
DELIMITER ;

call cierreMes('4B MC','SANTANDER',3,2013, @total, @nulas, @erroneas);

select @total, @nulas, @erroneas;
```

> When i do "call" @nulas and @erroneas return a value, but @total
>   nothing.

With select total, its works fine. but no returns a value, in this select : select @total, @nulas, @erroneas; @total is null.

Comment: Hi! it´s solved. The problem is in this line: declare total int default 0; Deleting the problem dissapears.

Answer (score 0):

You calculate `total` with this formula:

```
set total =(stockActual + entrada) - (salida + cantidad);
```

If one of the values used in the calculation is `NULL`, then total will be `NULL`.

I can see set statements for `entrada`, `salida`, and `cantidad`. But what is the value of `stockActual`?

It seems you are missing a statement that will set the value of `stockActual`.

Comment: Thanks its solved. the problem was that i inizialite total :declare total int default 0; and doesn´t necessary because its inizialite in  the header.